# Shaping neural network classification output dimensions?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, neural-network, keras

I am receiving the following error when I fit the network - ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_6 to have shape (2,) but got array with shape (22,)

As far as I can tell the shape should be correct given how the dataset is split? Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

The dataset can be found here: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/mushroom/agaricus-lepiota.data

```
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import Sequential
import keras.utils
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# seed weights
np.random.seed(3)

# import dataset
data = pd.read_csv('agaricus-lepiota.csv', delimiter=',')

# encode labels as integers so the can be one-hot-encoded which takes int matrix
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
data = data.apply(le.fit_transform)

# one-hot-encode string data (now type int)
ohe = preprocessing.OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
data = ohe.fit_transform(data)

X = data[:, 1:23]
Y = data[:, 0:1]

# split into test and train set
x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=.2, random_state=5)

# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(500, input_dim=22, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(300, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(25, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), epochs=1000, batch_size=25)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found 2 errors in your code.

1)

```
x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=.2, random_state=5)
```

must be

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=.2, random_state=5)
```

check [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) to learn more about the function.

2)

You have only one column in y_train. But the last layer in your model adds two columns. So instead of

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(500, input_dim=22, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(300, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(25, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))
```

use this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(500, input_dim=22, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(300, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(25, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```